# Como puedo validar si existe o no un esquema en postgres desde php?

Tags: php, postgresql

Comienzo a trabajar con postgres y quiero saber como puedo validar si existe o no un Esquema en postgres desde php?

En pg admin lo puedo verificar sin problema (devuelve `true` o `false`). Pero desde php al validarlo con la misma sentencia en un `if` me devuelve siempre verdadero extista o no el Esquema.

Supongo que simpre es verdadero porque independientemente del resultado se ejecuta y se muestra un resultado valga la redunancia.

he probado con `count()`,`sizeof()` y mas pero sigue mostrando verdadero

```
//este es un fragmento del metodo
    $sql = "SELECT exists(select schema_name FROM 
           information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name 
           ='{$nameTenant}')";

    $this->querySql($sql);
    $this->stmt->execute();
    $res = $this->stmt->fetchAll();

    if (($res) == true) {
      print_r($res);//
      echo 'existe ' . '<br>';
    } else {
      print_r($res);
      echo 'No existe ' . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué hay en la variable  `$sql`?

Comment: Hola, acabo de editar la pregunta y puse el contenido de la variable...

Comment: Recuerda que `fetchAll` te devuelve un array y puede que esté validad un array vacío como true

Comment: Otra cosa que veo es que estás sobrescribiendo a la variable $res.

Comment: Faltan detalles en ese contexto. No sabemos lo que es `$this`, es la clase actual, OK, pero, ¿representa a la conexión realmente? además, ¿qué es `querySql()`? ¿qué haces en esa función?

Comment: @gaidyjg exacto por eso siempre me dice verdadero. Da igual si esta vacio o no lo esta retornando. Recorriendo el array pude validarlo. Pero no entiendo el motivo por el cual sin usar fetchAll igual sigue dando verdadero. Gracias!

Comment: @A.Cedano Si es el metodo que retorna solo la conexion y el prepare().

Comment: @JavierSnachez Ah solo se quedo asi por que estaba testeando pero no es el causante grax.

Comment: Muestra el código, pues no sabemos si hay algo mal en ese método. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.